# How Do I Set Up A Secure Remote Developer VM?

Tags: azure, security, remote-desktop

We have a bring your own device program in our company but after a security review we can't let users/developers have admin access, use removable drives, download Azure data etc.
Essentially, we need them to do all their work on VMs instead of their own PCs.

The simplest solution here seems to be to create *remote* VMs (i.e. not locally using Virtualbox) for developers to do their work on instead of using their PCs directly.

Is there a way to do this using Azure or do we have to purchase a Citrix license?

Comment: I'd get another reviewer to review the security review because that conclusion is a bit... preposterous. Unless you work on credit card processing or intelligence services, these restrictions are paranoid. If you did, you wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: Besides, what you ask is information on Azure services, not programming. Azure already offers desktop virtualization (that's the name of what you ask). Github offers [Github Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces) that allow you to use VS Code for editing and spin up fully configured VMs on Azure to execute the code, host servers etc. These services cost though - why don't you just buy new laptops for developers?

Comment: The reason for the security review is that our work is with banks and the service contains bank client personal data. We are a very small startup and almost everything in the cloud and we don't have resources in place to buy laptops and secure them etc. It sounds like we need something like GitHub Codespaces except we use different IDEs than Visual Code and have requirements for running other things like Docker, java processes for testing etc

Comment: SO is a Q&A site for specific programming problems. This isn't a programming problem. Dekstop virtualization is a service offered by multiple cloud providers. So are VMs and other managed services. Beyond that you'll have to do the math to see if using VMs and virtual desktops is cheaper than buying machines. Over a single year buying is probably cheaper. Securing though is a different story. Not that you don't need administration and securing on the cloud. You'd also have to ensure everyone has adequate internet connections. Remote desktop/VNC needs a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: Besides, all cloud providers charge for outbound traffic, which means you'll end up paying for the RDP/VNC traffic. You also get a lot of latency, no matter the bandwidth. Github Codespases solves this by *not* using a virtual desktop, only moving text commands between the cloud and the local editor. Latency is eliminated because you still work locally